# Iterative solution for constructing a BST from a sorted linked list

Tags: algorithm

I want to create a BST from a sorted linked list. I have solved the problem for recursively but was wondering how to write an iterative solution for the same without changing the complexity of the problem.

[EDIT]

Note: I do not want to implement my own stack.

[EDIT2]

The function that recursively calls itself be f. Pseudo code is given below. Call f with head pointer from `main`

```
node * f(int start_index, int end_index, node *ptr) {
     if ( start>end) return NULL
     middle_index = start_index + (end_index-start_index)/2
     node *l_child = f(start_index, middle_index-1, ptr)
     initialize parent with ptr's value 
     parent->left = l_child
     ptr = ptr->next
     parent->right = f(middle_index+1, end, ptr)
     return parent
}
```

Comment: Can you add the recursive code that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ahead of time that you want it to be like so, roughly:

```
    _______
   /       \
  / \     / \
 /   \   /   \
/ \ / \ / \ /
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

then you can explicitly solve for the structure. In this case, for a list of length L<2<sup>N</sup> for some integer N, and assuming you create all nodes and leave some leaves as "null" (or alternatively don't even construct those nodes), you have the total number of nodes in the tree equal to (2*2<sup>N</sup>)-1. Your nodes would look like:

```
    12345678
   /       \
  1234    5678
  / \     / \
 12  34  56  78
/ \ / \ / \ / \
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I mentioned the size of the nodes because it should give us insight into how to proceed: there ought to be some way to enumerate `{1,2}->12, {3,4}->34, {12,34}->1234, ...`. One way to proceed is to start grouping nodes from the bottom. For example, we could do this in N (3) passes:

```
step 1:    1  2   3  4    5  6   7
step 2:   (1  2) (3  4)  (5  6) (7   )
step 3:  ((1  2) (3  4))((5  6) (7   ))
step 4: (((1  2) (3  4))((5  6) (7   )))
```

Another alternative is to use a stack to keep track of the higher level nodes as we group them.

Another way is to create an explicit formula for the structure. We create 7 nodes and set their children as follows: `{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,null}, {12,34}, {56,78}, {1234,5678}`. In particular if we index the nodes in a linear scheme, this pattern would be: `9={1,2}, 10={3,4}, 11={5,6}, 12={7,null}, 13={9,10}, 14={11,12}, 15={13,14}`. Simply incrementing appears to give the exact pattern of a balanced binary tree. This will use no additional memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert any recursive solution to an "iterative" solution by simulating a stack.

Comment: yes but that is not I want to do, I mean without using any external memory.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: you can probably (ab)use some pointer on the `node*` objects to simulate the stack while building the tree.